# CMake: how to select a different shell

Tags: c++, bash, cmake, clang

Using CMake, how to choose the shell to be used? Mine seems to be set to `sh` by default, but I need some environment vars loaded from my .bashrc, and I guess changing the shell is the way to go.

I'm actually trying to set `clang++` as the C++ compiler, with the following directive:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
```

But when I try to compile the code, the shell being used is `sh`, and it does not find `clang++`, as I make the binary visible via the following `export`, in my .bashrc:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:~/llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/"
```

Here is the error, confirming `sh` cannot find the `clang++` binary:

```
$ make
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/floyd-warshall.dir/main.cpp.o
/bin/sh: 1: clang++: not found
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/floyd-warshall.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/floyd-warshall.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: That's weird... that doesn't look like a CMake error message. Could you post the full error log?

Comment: try `which clang++` in the shell where you're executing `cmake`. The error probably shows up because clang++ isn't in the path of the shell where you execute `cmake`.

Comment: @Samveen Weird, `which` does not find `clang++`, although I'm able to execute it directly with `clang++`. I mean, the current session reckons `clang++`, and executes it properly.

Comment: @Guillaume I don't think it adds much, but I've made an edit with the entire error.

Comment: @Rubens try `type clang++` and `alias|grep clang` as well. It may as well be an alias.

Comment: @Samveen The output for type: `clang++ is hashed (/home/rubens/llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang++)`; there is no alias set for clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not force the c++ compiler this way in your cmake file (at first I thought you were using a toolchain file). Remove that line and let CMake finds the compiler by itself. To use clang++ set some environment variables before calling cmake. Something like:

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
cmake /path/to/your/project
make
```

Comment: Yep, this was the solution I found googling, but I thought there should be some way other than adding `export`s in my .bashrc. I was thinking about changing the shell, from `sh`, to `bash`; guess there might be no better solution, though.

Comment: Another solution would be to use a toolchain file: move your "set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)" statement in a toolchain.cmake file and then call cmake /path/to/your/project -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/toolchain.cmake